Class extends value /static/media/client.98866d6736d9f36d61b8.cjs is not a constructor or null @solana/web3.js @coral-xyz/anchor
Getting this error just by importing these two dependencies:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import {Connection, Publicky, clusterApiUrl} from "@solana/web3.js";
Class extends value /static/media/client.98866d6736d9f36d61b8.cjs is not a constructor or null
TypeError: Class extends value /static/media/client.98866d6736d9f36d61b8.cjs is not a constructor or null
at ./node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.browser.esm.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13261:34)
at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85444:31)
at webpack_require (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84873:32)
at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85102:21)
at ./node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/browser/index.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:332:73)
at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85444:31)
at webpack_require (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:84873:32)
at fn (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85102:21)
at ./src/App.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17:75)
at options.factory (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:85444:31)

Please post an MRE of your code giving this error, otherwise we're just guessing.

I resolved the same issue by installing @solana/web3.js@1.91.6.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
